# How to keep 'n' at the startvalue in a range?

Tags: vim, range

example:

```
for n in range(startvalue,endvalue)
  if .... 
     exe n."j"
     "dont go to next n, keep startvalue" 
     let endvalue = endvalue-1
  else
     do this
  endif
  "go to next n"
endfor
```

I want to keep the startvalue if some condition exists.
But I don't know how to keep the startvalue.
I tried to do this without success:

```
let n=n-1
let startvalue=startvalue-1
```

Comment: Are you looking for perl's redo?
What are you exactly trying to achieve? In some situations, `map()`+`filter()` will be the perfect tools, some times, you'll have to go to the old way to loop: `let i =0 ; while i < max ; ... ; let i+=1 or let max -= 1 ; endwhile`

Comment: @LucHermitte, I'm joining lines in this function. If there is a line to join, the startvalue of the loop must remain the same (because the line is still the same) but the endvalue has to be lowered with 1. If there is no line to join go to next value in range.

Comment: @LucHermitte, tried your solution. That resolved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know w/o more context, but if the "if ...." gives the same result the next time through with that value of n, then you have created an infinite loop (bad). If that's not true, you could try "let n=startvalue-1" where you have "dont go to next n, keep startvalue".

In general, you do *not* want to be modifying loop variables inside of loops. It would be much cleaner to wrap your for loop in a while loop and to break out of the for loop each time your condition is met, testing first to see if you're completely done with looping. Something like:

```
let done = false
while (not done)
    for n in range(startvalue,endvalue)
        if .... 
            exe n."j"
            if completely done
                done = true
            break 
        else
            do this
        endif
    endfor
endwhile
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just tried `let n=startvalue-1` but that doesn't do what I want. It just goes as before to the next 'n'

Comment: btw.. it doesn't create an infinite loop because I lowered the endvalue. :)